# Finding MAP estimate

Tags: distributions, bayesian, estimation, posterior, map-estimation

I think after all the reading I've done I still don't fully understand MAP estimation. I came across a problem that's leaving me dumbfounded.

Suppose $A$ ~  $N(0,\sigma^2_1) $ and $\epsilon$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2_2)$

Let's say $a$ is drawn from the distribution of $A$ and that we observe $b$, which is conditioned on $a$, coming from a random variable $B$:

$b = a + \epsilon$

The questions asks me to find a MAP estimate of $a$ given $b$.

This seems so simple and yet I'm confused - I thought the point of MAP estimation was to use Bayes rule to determine the posterior by multiplying the likelihood and the prior - but I don't see what the prior on $a$ is here. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: The prior on $A$ is a $N(0,\sigma^2_1)$ distribution, with $b$ a realisation of a $N(a,\sigma^2_2)$ distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about your understanding of the prior and posterior concepts. Having $X\sim f(x)$ is *prior* information. Because, without knowing extra details, you know how really $X$ is distributed. So, $A\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$ means $A$'s prior distribution is normal with mean $0$, and variance $\sigma_1^2$.

Posterior distibution is obtained after having some additional data. For example, here it is $f_{A|B}(a|b)$, i.e. the density of $A$ when we know that $B=b$. MAP estimates maximizes the posterior distribution, but commonly we don't derive the posterior and then maximize it. Posterior density is proportional to the multiplication of *likelihood* and the *prior* due to Bayes Rule, i.e. $f_{A|B}(a|b)\propto f_{B|A}(b|a)f_A(a)$. So, we maximize this multiplication and find $\hat{a}_{MAP}$.

You know the prior, $f_A(a)$. $f_{B|A}(b|a)$ is $N(a,\sigma_2^2)$ as in @Xi'an's comment, because if $a$ is given, it just acts as a shifter to $\epsilon$. A normal variable that is shifted towards some direction is also a normal RV, with shifted mean and the same variance.

You'll just multiply these two densities, and maximize.

Comment: This makes sense. As a follow up, if I was instead not explicitly told the distribution of $A$, but was told, for example, that $A$ can take values +1 or -1, with equal probabilities, then can I still infer the distribution of $A$ to get the prior information?

Comment: Yes, when you know how A is distributed, i.e. PDF or PMF, you know the prior. It doesn't matter if the distribution has a name or not.